# SQL Query not throwing error even if the entered scale value is higher than specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For a requirement, I need to capture the numeric values without truncation. But the output value is getting truncated even though i specified the Scale as '2'.

Column **'A'** datatype - ***numeric(5,2)***

**Case 1:**

**Entered value:** `123.55689335218777665555777778899995544`

**Output :** `123.56`

**Case 2:**

**Entered value:** `1234.55689335218777665555777778899995544`

**Output:** `Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.`

**Case 3:**

**Entered value:** `123.555689335218777665555777778899995544`

**Output:**`Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.`

My question is **why I am not receiving any error when the scale is higher than '2'** but I am getting error when the precision is higher than 3.

Comment: Trailing decimals are rounded, silently. But 1234 is too big for 3 digits. (-999.99 - 999.99 are allowed.)

Comment: @jarlh: Is there any way to avoid the rounding off/truncation?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. (You can do insert/update using stored procedures, where you check the value before modifying the table.)

Comment: @RGR . . . . If you need "infinite" precision in SQL Server, then you need to store the values as character strings.  Such precision wouldn't really be needed for values actually used for arithmetic, so such long numbers might be codes of some sort, that are really better stored as strings.

Comment: @jarlh : I am facing this issue in SSIS - Data conversion task. I simplified the question in this way for obvious reasons.

Comment: @RGR - if you need to put that data in the database, then you need to expand your data type.

Answer (score 0):

Why I am not receiving any error when the scale is higher than '2' but I am getting error when the precision is higher than 3.

```
Numeric(5,2):
```

It means your total number of digits is 5 among those 5 digits right most two digits are assigned for scale. (5-2=3) In your case your maximum allowed digits in the precision part is 3.

Note:

numeric(P,S)
P-Precision
S-Scale

Refer the example below

```
DECLARE @value NUMERIC(5, 2)

SET @value=123.55689335218777665555777778899995544

PRINT @value --Success

SET @value=1234.55689335218777665555777778899995544

PRINT @value --The value itself not able to convert because the number of digits exceeds 38

SET @value=123.555689335218777665555777778899995544

PRINT @value --The value itself not able to convert because the number of digits exceeds 38
```

Comment: Yes. The allowed part in scale is '2' right? Then why it is not throwing error  when i entered more than 2 in scale but just it truncates?

Comment: This is an implicit rounding handled by SQL Server. This will not truncate it rounds the value to 2 decimals even though when you give many number of digits.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid it from rounding off?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100667/discussion-between-rgr-and-newuser).